# How to add eventlistener to object in Html Object Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading an external website in my website through HTML Object tag and I want to catch the right click inside the Object through a addEventListener, but I can't figure out how.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            function fill(){
                var miobj = document.getElementById('miobj');
                miobj.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleEvent, true);
                document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleEvent, true);
            }

            function handleEvent (event) {
                alert("working");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="fill" onclick="fill()">Fill</button>
    <object id='miobj' style="width:800px;height:600px;" data="http://validator.w3.org/" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I click my button, eventlistener is added to my document, so, if I right click the button(or anywhere in my document), the "working" alert pops, but if I right click inside the website loaded in object, nothing happens. I want to do this to prevent right clicks inside the object. So there's gotta be a way.

I know there's must be something missing to the way I referencing 'miobj', it should be like:

```
var miobj = document.getElementById('miobj').window;
```

or something, and I have tried several ways, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I also know this can be done because this [chrome extension](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNlvjuz5XKAhVN5mMKHYDvA0kQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fenable-right-click%2Fhhojmcideegachlhfgfdhailpfhgknjm%3Fhl%3Des&usg=AFQjCNGDu3AcI-Aly_el-P_AIzbVjQYMUQ&bvm=bv.110151844,d.cGc) does the opposite of what I'm trying to do, and it works, If I load a right click disabled website into my website, the extension enables the right click inside the website.

Anyone got any idea on how to accomplish this?