# How to append element to HTML Object Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm having an issue where I want to disable right click at a website loaded in my website in a HTML Object tag, as explained here [How to add eventlistener to object in Html Object Tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638557/how-to-add-eventlistener-to-object-in-html-object-tag), I found this google extension ([Enable right click](https://github.com/kyo-ago/enable-right-click)) which does the opposite of what I want.

Reading all the code and analizing what it does, I found out that when a site is loaded, it appends a script to the document body, which enables right clicking catching the contextmenu event and stopping the propagation or something like that, it works.

So I just added the script to my website and it didn't work on the website loaded inside the HTML Object tag, it works everywhere else. BUT when using the extension it did work in the website loaded inside the HTML Object tag.

So I made several tests and debugging, and found out that when website is loaded inside the HTML Object tag, the extension ALSO appends the script inside its body, take for example this simple code (very similar to the one used on my previous post):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        function fill(){
            document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleEvent, true);
        }

        function handleEvent (event) {
            alert("working");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="fill" onclick="fill()">Fill</button>
    <object id='miobj' style="width:800px;height:600px;" data="http://validator.w3.org/" />
</body>
</html>
```

I include my script in the html, but what the extension does is to append the script through a content script(which I don't really know when it is fired):

```
var scp = document.createElement('script');
scp.src = chrome.extension.getURL('web_accessible_resources/index.js');
document.body.appendChild(scp);
function postWebAccessibleResourceMessage (flag) {
    window.postMessage({
        'type': 'enable-right-click',
        'disableRightClick': flag
    }, '*');
}
```

So, with the extension enabled, it appends its script (web_accessible_resources/index.js) to the body, but it also appends it to the body inside the HTML Object tag.

Obviously the extension has a few more scripts, but the principle remains, so if I could append a script to the body in the website loaded inside the HTML Object tag, I could accomplish what I want to do.

Any ideas how could I append my script to the website loaded inside the HTML Object tag?

**EDIT:**
If you can't do this due to same origin policy, why is a chrome extension able to do it?

Comment: It's the same security issue as with your input question. You cannot make changes across domains like that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: But if the extension is doing it, how does it do it?

Comment: extensions have different permissions than web pages. also, don't disable right click.

Comment: Different permissions how? Also, what I really want is to enable right click on a website who has it disabled, but when I created my example I used a right click enabled website, so I said I wanted to disable it, I just thought for no reason that it would be easier than saying "Imagine this website has right click disabled, and what I want to do is to enable it", so I just went with it. Now I realize explaining this got even harder.